# Byte array to string conversion

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth

I'm making an Android app that communicates with bluetooth device. I'm writing a specific message to chosen characteristic as follows:

```
byte[] clearDataset = new byte [0x0A];
Log.d("uploadDataset", "Message: " + Converters.byteArrayToHexString(clearDataset, 0, clearDataset.length));
writeCharacteristic(Converters.byteArrayToHexString(clearDataset, 0, clearDataset.length), Constants.DIAG_WRITE);
```

My conversion function looks like this:

```
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes, int startingByte , int endingByte) {
        byte[] shortenBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, startingByte, endingByte);
        final byte[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        byte[] hexChars = new byte[shortenBytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < shortenBytes.length; j++) {
            int v = shortenBytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < new String(hexChars, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length(); i += 2) {
            String str = new String(hexChars, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).substring(i, i + 2);
            output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out why in this case my conversion output looks like this:

> D/uploadDataset: Message: ��������������������

It is strange, because the same conversion function works perfectly fine when I'm using it to translate the values that I'm receiving as bluetooth notification. Any suggestions where the problem lies are welcome

Comment: `byte[] clearDataset = new byte [0x0A];` There is nothing in your array. All byte values are random. But... you should get a nice hex string of course. Values are not important.

Comment: @blackapps I'm this function is also used in other parts of app, where I wanted to be able to remove some parts of byte array that I have received. For example the byte array contained validation and response type byte that were not necessary for me. In some cases I just wanted to access the data directly

Comment: It's not a problem, to change the name of variables, but I don't see how renaming should affect the output of the function

Comment: If you don't understand what I'm trying to achieve it's fine. I can provide you more details what I'm trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240603/discussion-between-julian-modlinski-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps why you deleted your comments ? :)

Comment: Well they are not needed anymore except for the first one on which you did not react. Please react on my first comment.

Comment: do you know the answer to the question or not really? again it's completely fine to not know something :)

Comment: You still have not reacted to my first comment.

Comment: I will address it as soon as I will fix the main issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away your StringBuilder stuff.

```
 return new String(hexChars);
```

Comment: Strangely it works, but could you tell me why in this case I need to get rid of StringBuilder? I assume it is the same situation when I'm receiving the value from characteristic in onCharacteristicChanged callback. In this StringBuilder is necessary for proper conversion

Comment: I dont know. Probably because you are messing around with charsets. You dont need charsets at all using only  "0123456789ABCDEF"

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java And the answer with 267 points. Only five code lines are enough. It makes no sense that you have different results when receiving from somewhere els.

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help and time :)